# Radio Buttons in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, radio-button, expandablelistview

I have Radio Buttons for children items in expandablelistview ( it also contains checkboxes). I want them(radio buttons) to act like a Radio group. I added code below in getChildView, however it doesn't work. Should i change this code?  and what should i add in onChildClickListener?

```
if (rad_group.equals("rg1")) { // children, that should have radiobuttons

            rbut.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        mSelectedChildPosition = childPosition;
                        mSelectedGroupPosition = groupPosition;
                        notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                }
            });

            if (mSelectedChildPosition != childPosition && mSelectedGroupPosition != groupPosition) {
                rbut.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                rbut.setChecked(true);
                if (mSelectedRB != null && rbut != mSelectedRB) {
                    mSelectedRB = rbut;

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: When you say " it doesn't work." - can you explain the behaviour you get and what you expect?

Comment: Of course. If i have nothing in onChildClick method and have this code in getChildView, nothing happens. I click on item with radio button and it doesn't get checked.

Comment: Where do childPosition and groupPosition come from and which values do they have in the moment when the buttin is pressed? Did you try debugging that?

Comment: how shoud i initialise mSelectedRB? i did it like rbut - my common button

Comment: @HermannKlecker no, i didn't. i am a beginner and don't know how to do it

Comment: Oh, you should know how to work with the debugger. At least you should know how to print the value of something to the (debug-)console. Set a breakpoint on `mSelectedGroupPosition = groupPosition;` and run it for debugging (the bug symbol nex to the run symbol in most IDEs.)

Comment: Google how to debug with your IDE. If you don't know how to do that then you are looking forward so some rather frustrating developer's live.

Comment: @HermannKlecker i did it and saw child and group position

Comment: there is no solution to my problem?

Comment: You may have to share more of your code. What do you do with `mSelectedRB`? Apparently it never gets any value. You better remove `mSelectedRB != null &&` from your code.

Comment: Right, not answering our questions will not help. Not providing more code will not help.